# Introspecting quantum circuit execution on Qiskit Aer simulators

Tags: programming, qiskit, simulation

Is there any way to get information from intermediate points in the execution of a quantum circuit. This is not possible on real quantum hardware but would be very useful on the Aer simulators for both learning quantum programming and for debugging.

Comment: A short answer for now: check out the snapshot function introduced in 0.5 https://medium.com/qiskit/program-quantum-computers-more-easily-with-qiskit-0-5-802d1e4a338d

Comment: Thanks @JamesWootton. I do not think this is currently implemented though: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/65ba65d0f88aa586c1c6cb25b709f4709bbeb287/qiskit/providers/builtinsimulators/statevector_simulator.py#L80

Answer (score 3):

This feature is now available using the `snapshot` function of Qiskit Aer. Snapshots can be added to the circuit and the values are then returned in the results object.

This is an example of how you can create a circuit, add a snapshot to it and then get the result:

```
from qiskit import *

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.snapshot('1')             # add a snapshot with the key '1'
qc.h(0)                      # add more gates after the snapshot

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = execute(qc, backend).result()
snapshots = result.data()['snapshots']['statevector']
```

`snapshots` now contains a dictionary where the keys are the names given to the snapshots, and the values are an array of state vectors associated with that key.

In this example it is`{'1': [[[0.7071067811865476, 0.0], [0.7071067811865475, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]]}`.